# Get everything to the left of ? in a string during dplyr chain with mutate

Tags: r, stringr

```
df <- data.frame(
  strings = c('blah?ha', 'foo?bar', 'cats?dogs')
)

df %>% 
  mutate(first_word = str_split(strings, fixed('?')))

     strings first_word
 strings first_word
1   blah?ha   blah, ha
2   foo?bar   foo, bar
3 cats?dogs cats, dogs
```

This gets me close to my goal. I just want the first part though, blah, foo and cats. Tried:

```
 df %>% 
+   mutate(first_word = str_split(strings, fixed('?'))[[1]][[1]])
    strings first_word
1   blah?ha       blah
2   foo?bar       blah
3 cats?dogs       blah
```

This gives me the same word repeated down the column.

How can I get a new column with the values blah, foo and cats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` to match one or more characters that are not a `?` (`[^?]+`) from the start (`^`) Of the string

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(first_word = str_extract(strings, "^[^?]+"))
```

---

Or use `trimws` with `whitespace` as a regex

```
df %>%
    mutate(first_word = trimws(strings, whitespace = "\\?.*"))
```

Or similar code in `base R`

```
df$first_word <- with(df, trimws(strings, whitespace = "\\?.*"))
```

---

The issue in OP's code is that it is extracting only the first `list` element (`[[1]]`) from the `str_split`.  It needs to loop over the `list` and get the `first` element

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(first_word = map_chr(str_split(strings, fixed("?")), first))
#    strings first_word
#1   blah?ha       blah
#2   foo?bar        foo
#3 cats?dogs       cats
```